# How do I correct the iOS7 photo app's location guess?

Tags: photos, ios

iOS7 organizes photos into automatic groups. It labels each group with a location. It often chooses the wrong location.
For example if you're at the supermarket it might say "Anytown Post Office" if there happens to be a post office near by

How do I correct it with the correct location? In the example above I want the group labeled "Supermarket" instead of "Post Office"

Answer (score 1):

You can edit this in iPhoto on your mac, but only on the local copy not the Photo Stream copy. On the iPhone you'd want to get a metadata editor app such as [EXIF-fi](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-fi-photo-gps-exif-viewer/id574247475?mt=8) ($.99)